# Dynamic TEMPLATE_DIRS

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to have dynamic directories where templates will reside. Let me explain what I mean. I have an application `system` wich has such a file structure:

```
\proj
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    ...
\system
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py
    \modules
        \module_1
            __init__.py
            models.py
            views.py
            urls.py
            \templates     ## Attention
                one.html
                two.html
        \module_2
            __init__.py
            modules.py
            \templates    ##
                three.html
                four.html
        ...
        \module_N
            ...
```

As you can see there is a `modules` folder, which contains "atomic" modules, atomic in a sense that they have all necessary files, including templates in one place. So that `module_1` has a template folder with its tempaltes, `module_2` has a templates folder and all other modules have their own templates folder. What I want is to be able to refer to these templates folders in my `settings.py` file, so that when I upload a brand new module to modules folder, I would not have to change this `settings.py` file. So my question is, how can I dynamically build `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    ## how to implement this???
)
```

**EDIT**

I'm considering another approach. First, to convert my modules to dinamic applications like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027901/dynamically-loading-django-apps-at-runtime):

```
MODULES_DIR = 'system/modules'

for item in os.listdir(MODULES_DIR):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(MODULES_DIR, item)):
        app_name = 'system.modules.%s' % item
        INSTALLED_APPS += (app_name, )
```

And then to do something to make Django look for templates in all applications' folders. But I'm not sure whether it will work and how can I complete this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply app-specific templates, which is already catered for by the [`APP_DIRS` flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates) in the template settings dict. There shouldn't be any other configuration needed.

Comment: And will my approach of building INSTALLED_APPS dynamically work?

Comment: I suspect that will depend on when that code runs; you will probably run into difficulties with the startup order. I must say though I can't see why you're doing this; if you're adding code to your project, it's trivial to add that code's app name to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: And I'm not sure that I understand documentation right. Can you, please, correct me, if I am mistaken? As far as I can gather, I should have all my modules listed in INSTALLED_APPS (statically, or dynamically if it is possible). And then just have APP_DIRS = True. And all this should be done in settings.py file.

Comment: " I must say though I can't see why you're doing this; " The idea is to enable users to upload new modules from a remote server without having to change any code.