# Can't import django.apps within script

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-apps

I have test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys, subprocess, time, re
from django.conf import settings
from django.apps import apps
import django

django.setup()

"""
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027901/dynamically-loading-django-apps-at-runtime
"""

MAIN_IMPORTS = """\
from django.test import TestCase
from model_mommy import mommy

"""

IMPORT_STATEMENT = """\
from clientsite.{app}.models import {models}
"""

TEST_BLOCK = """\
class {modelname}CreationTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.model = {modelname}

    def test_create(self):
        x = mommy.make(self.model)
        x.save()
        self.assertTrue(x.pk)

    def test_factory_isinstance(self):
        x = mommy.make(self.model)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(x, {modelname}))
"""

all_apps = apps.get_apps()
all_models = apps.get_models()
model_info = apps.all_models
```

I want to be able to use `django.apps` within my script. The script is within an app like `mysite/mommy_app/scripts/testtasm.py`

I tried

```
cchilders:~/work_projects/mysite [ckc/fixture-replacements]$ ./manage.py mysite/mommy_models/scripts/testtasm.py 
Unknown command: 'mysite/mommy_models/scripts/testtasm.py'
```

and failed.

`django.setup()` also failed.

How can I use django features within a script without actually running runserver? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running it as a normal python script?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `manage.py` to run your script, unless you have created a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/)

You should run the script with

```
python mysite/mommy_models/scripts/testtasm.py
```

Or, if the script is executable

```
mysite/mommy_models/scripts/testtasm.py
```

In the script, before you call `django.setup`, you must set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable. You may also have to add your project directory to the Python path.

```
import os
import sys
# This should be the directory that contains the directory containing settings.py
sys.path.append('/path/to/mysite') 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

django.setup()

# now you can import the settings and access them
from django.conf import settings
```