# DJANGO Install application on runtime

Tags: django

I have an application which is made of several apps. The thing is that by default, only 1 app is installed. I called it 'base'. This `base` app enables the user to manage users, groups (but that isn't the point here) **AND should enable users to install other apps on runtime** (that is the point).

I created an `Application` model.
In my UI, I list all the applications with a button `install` aside of it.

The idea is, when I click on this button, to :

- Mark the application as installed
- Add it to the App registry on runtime (that's the blocking point)
- Apply the migration for this app

So here are some samples of code :

> My Application model :

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.core import management
from django.db import models


class Application(models.Model):

  class Meta:
      db_table = 'base_application'

  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  verbose_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  version = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
  summary = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  is_installed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_uninstallable = models.BooleanField()
```

> My install() method would look like :

I know there are mistakes in it and that is the point of this question. I don't understand how the App Registry actually works.

*Note that I must provide the reverse of it too (uninstall)*

```
    def install(self):
      self.is_installed = True
      self.save()
      settings.INSTALLED_APPS.append(self.name)
      apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      self.migrate()
```

> My migrate() method :

```
    def migrate(self):
        management.call_command('makemigrations', self.name, interactive=False)
        management.call_command('migrate', self.name, interactive=False)
```

The usual error I get is `No installed app with label ....`

Thanks in advance for your help. I can precise if needed.

Comment: Check this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027901/dynamically-loading-django-apps-at-runtime

Comment: Yeah I've already read it many times and I still can't make my mind on it. That's why I asked here, considering I'm doing something completely silly that someone would tell me.

Comment: @CatalinHoha Well finally I made it work but  how do I know if `apps_ready` `models_ready` `loading` and `ready` have to be `False` ? I've seen people only setting `ready` to `False`. This part of Django is not really well documented in my opinion.