# Django implement installable plugins at runtime

Tags: python, django

I want to made Django app that allows creation and then installation of plugins, or modules, for it, somewhat like you can do in CMS.

Creator of plugin should define models, some configuration settings and handler functions for actions. Plugin will provide only REST api, so no templates required.
Plugins must be installed at runtime - creator fills form, attaches archive with code, and plugin gets installed and activated.

Unfortunately, my understanding of Django internals is way too low for this task.
The most tricky part is runtime installation. [There is answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027901/dynamically-loading-django-apps-at-runtime) how to install django app at runtime, but it feels hacky.
Also, there is lib called [django-pluggins](https://github.com/krischer/django-plugins), but it works with older version of Django and seems unmaintained.

So, the question is, what approach/libs should I use to implement this.

Comment: You have not asked any question or provided any code.

Comment: I thought question is obvious, but added it explicitly.

Comment: Well, "what approach/libs" is too broad. The most Python-standard approach would be to only accept proper Python `.whl` files, use `pip` (as a library or subprocess) to install them, and use e.g. setuptools entrypoints to discover plugins from installed packages.

Comment: Well, I thought there's django specific approach